# php Code to change Get value

Tags: php

I have a code where I pull a mobile number to a new page with the following code

```
<a href="control_clientinfo.php?member_id=<? echo $rows['member_id']; ?>" 
class="update">Look Up</a>
```

The problem is I have already got hundreds of numbers in the SQL database but the system requires that I use the following format

27827123455 at this stage all our numbers are saved in this format 0827123455. Is there away that i can write the code to drop the 0 and add 27 in front of it automatically or would it be easier to change all the numbers to the desired format

This is the URL I need

```
www.page.co.za/control_clientinfo.php?27827123455
```

at this stage I am getting the following format

```
www.page.co.za/control_clientinfo.php?0827123455
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be as simple as this:

```
$number = "0827..."
$other_number = "27".substr($number, 1);
```

In your case:

```
<a href="control_clientinfo.php?member_id=<? echo "27".substr($rows['member_id'], 1); ?>" 
class="update">Look Up</a>
```

Comment: That could work dropping the first number but how would I implement it into the code on the link without running another PHP page

Just to add the member_id is echo'd from SQL database

Comment: I updated my question. But if you really needed that update to fix your problem, you shouldn't be touching (PHP) code.